# Change appxupload file name in Windows Application Packaging Project

Tags: uwp, packaging, desktop-bridge, appx

I am preparing an appxupload package file for submission to Microsoft Store using Windows Application Packaging Project in Visual Studio 2017. In my solution, there are following projects.

- MyApp (WPF desktop application project)
- MyApp.Packager (Windows Application Packaging Project)

When I create an appxupload file by "Create App Packages" function, the name of the output appxupload file is automatically set to the following format.

`MyApp.Packager_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU_bundle.appxupload`

However, I would like to change this format to the following:

`MyApp_1.0.0.0_AnyCPU_bundle.appxupload`

I have searched the settings of the packaging project to set the output file name but I couldn't find it. So, is it possible to change the output file name by specifying it in some settings files? Or is there any workaround for this purpose?

Comment: Previously I rename my appxupload package and it can be uploaded to the store successfully.So could you modify the name of the appxupload file manually to try?

Comment: @DasiyTianMSFT Thank you for your suggestion. I manually changed the file name of an appxupload file and confirmed that it could be successfully uploaded to Microsoft Store. It is one solution.

Comment: Thanks for your  feedback, I will update the suggestion comment as an answer which is beneficial to other communities to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could rename the appxupload package directly and upload it to the Dashboard as usual. Normally, it can be identified by the store, as long as you use the [Windows Application Packaging Project packaging steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-packaging-dot-net#create-a-package) without problems.